# Read & Combine Data From Multiple Excel Files with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read several excel files from a directory into pandas and concatenate them into one big dataframe. I have not been able to figure it out though. All the files have 5 columns which are:

```
 C   N    S    R   Q
```

Except one file that has 7 columns which are

```
D   I   C    N   QI   P  L
```

How can i get a one big dataframe with these columns

```
C   N    S    R   Q
```

Code :

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = #path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

NB : I don't have same columns in all my files

How can i fix this?

Comment: Which columns of the 7 column data do you want? C, N and Q?
And are the column names all the same, or different between your 5-column files?

Comment: @AlfredRodenboog All the files have the same column name expect the file with 7 columns. I want The C, N et QI (which the Q in the other files)

Answer (score 0):

Just add what columns you want to keep and select them from the dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = #path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []
cols_to_keep = ['C', 'N', 'S', 'R', 'Q']

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df[cols_to_keep])

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```